# Finish (Close) a Android Activity on Touch

Tags: android

How to terminate an Activity in Adroid on touch. Here i shows a view which is described in details.xml. I need to dismiss the activity on touch. I tried the following code. But its not working. Any ideas?

```
public class Details extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);
    }
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        this.finish();
        return true;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that onTouchEvent is getting called? The API docs mention that it will only be called as last resort if none of the child views consumed the event.

Comment: i think its not getting called. Do you have any idea how to add "onTouchEvent" to the view that im using.Because here im using it from a xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your onTouchEvent() will only be called if no other views under the finger in the view hierarchy have consumed the event.  This is uncommon, since many views do interact with touch events.
2. It is wrong to do stuff in onTouchEvent() without look at what the actual event is.
3. Generally you should implement a view that reacts to touches and does the appropriate thing.

Comment: Can you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628687/problem-in-android-creating-a-view-dynamically

Answer (score 6):

You should use

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    finish();
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question but my solution is this if anyone need it:

I had the same problem so I solved it with giving my parent layout i.e(consraintLayout) an id then calling finish() in setOnClickListener() method and it worked.

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.validateLayout);

    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

validateLayout is parent constraint layout of my activity.

any review is welcomed.

Also i want to know if suggestion of Addev is better then this code.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't install a listener in onCreate(). Like:
findViewById(R.id.some_view).setOnTouchListener(this);

Comment: He doesn't need one. He's trying to make it close the activity when the screen itself is touched.